# Not able to require a node module

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm new to node js and require js. I installed a node module via npm install(https://www.npmjs.org/package/box-view).  The node_modules folder has a box-view/index.js containing:

```
module.exports = {
BoxView: BoxView,
  createClient: function (key) {
    return new BoxView(key);
  }
};
```

When I try to access the module using require:

```
require ['box-view'], () ->
  console.log("Ready")
```

I get:
`GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/js/box-view.js 404 (Not Found).`
Looks like I'm doing a basic mistake. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're trying to require an array, make it a string. Also requiring modules doesn't magically make it available to a client.

Answer (score 0):

Node has a simple module loading system - files and modules are in one to one correspondence.

`var boxView = require('box-view');
console.log("Ready");`

Answer (score -1):

I think problem is because you did a `npm install box-view` so it will be under `node_modules/box_view/index.js`.

But using require you are just saying `require ['box-view']` so it's looking `./box-view.js`

This will work

```
 require(["node_modules/box-view/index"]
```

but this is not a good practice.

You should have a look on [require node manual](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2). It tells how to use requirejs with node.

Comment: please tell what is problem in this answer?

Comment: I have read that section in the Node manual at least ten times today.  Doesn't say anything about how to use the exported objects/functions after doing an npm install.  Also, changing the require statement gives: `GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/node_modules/box-view/index 404 (Not Found) `